# Run pdflatex in vim without a pop-up window

Tags: autocmd, filetype-tex

I currently have this autocommand in my vimrc: 
`autocmd BufWritePost *.tex silent! execute "!pdflatex %" | redraw!`

It compiles my current LaTeX file whenever I save with `:w`. However, a terminal window pops up every time I do so. `silent!` seems to ensure the window automatically closes after a few seconds, but it does not prevent it from opening in the first place.

Comment: What about using a plugin for compiling latex files which also parses errors & warnings and fills the quickfix list? You can configure vim for this on your own but you probably achieve this faster by using an existing plugin. I'd recommend [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). You can disable parts you do not want and only use the compile & quickfix functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vim 8, you could do something like

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.tex term ++close ++hidden pdflatex %
```

This should create a terminal buffer in vim running pdflatex, but keep it hidden and close it when the process exits.

But even better is to place your autocommand in a filetype plugin, so you can rely on that detection mechanism: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` can contain

```
autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> term ++close ++hidden pdflatex %
```

Comment: Why is your latter suggestion better?

Comment: Organisation, and better grouping @Harv. I put filetype stuff in ftplugins